# Laravel 5.5: Is there something like a Global Mutator for all Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel

All my models extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. What I want to achieve is each model to display `created_at`, `updated_at` and `deleted_at` in a specific date format or leave as `null` if date is not set when I retrieve / fetch data from DB (on fly).

I could use mutator and define `public function setCreatedAtAttribute()`, check if value is a Carbon date and then call desired `->format()` but I would have to do this (define this method) on each model for each date column.

On the other hand parent `Model` lives within `vendor` so I cannot modify it. Is there a way to define and apply it globally to all my models?

**PS. My question is not about modifying:**

```
/**
 * The storage format of the model's date columns.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat;
```

As *(if I understand correctly)* this is responsible for setting date format when storing data in the database. I want to leave it as it is. **So no change on the db level. I want to set new date format on retrieval on-fly.**

Comment: You could always use inheritance and create your own `Model` subclass which extends the Eloquent model.

Comment: Yes, but then I would have to replace `extends Model` with `extends MyModel` for all my models which also adds a bit of work (however doable). I thought there can be a quicker solution offered natively by Laravel. Thanks for comment btw.

Comment: This sounds like a standard inheritance problem. You're consolidating common functionality into a parent class. You could use find/replace to make this change in all your classes quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `trait` and use it in your models:

```
trait DatesTrait
{
    /**
     * Mutator for created_at
     */
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->formatDatetime($value);
    }

    /**
     * Mutator for updated_at
     */
    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->formatDatetime($value);
    }

    /**
     * Replace this with any formatting logic that suits your needs
     */
    protected function formatDatetime($value)
    {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);
        }

        return $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Then in each model:

```
class ModelX
{
    use DatesTrait;
}
```